# Missing attribute payment_processor_id of entity Contribution in API Explorer v3?

Tags: api, php7

I created a PHP 7 script that uses an API Call to get some information about a specific Contribution with a `$contributionID` that has been defined before.
The code (below) works and correctly returns `payment_processor_id`. BUT I cannot reproduce this in CiviCRM API Explorer v3.

My code is:

```
 $result2 = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', [
            'sequential' => "1",
            'return' => ["payment_processor","instrument_id","payment_instrument_id","payment_processor_id"],
            'id' => $contributionID,
        ]);
        $payment_instrument_id = $result2["values"]["0"]["payment_instrument_id"];
        $payment_processor_id = $result2["values"]["0"]["payment_processor_id"];
        echo "instrument ID: ";
        var_dump($payment_instrument_id);
        echo "processor ID: ";
        var_dump($payment_processor_id);
```

where the resulting array does correctly contain a value for `payment_instrument_id`.
When I try to reproduce this in API Explorer v3, I get an array response with the following structure:

```
    {
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "id": 885,
    "values": [
        {
            "contact_id": "2700",
            "contribution_id": "885",
            "payment_instrument_id": "8",
            "payment_instrument": "Lastschrift",
            "instrument_id": "8",
            "id": "885"
        }
    ]
}
```

Obviously, there is no `payment_processor_id` here. So it is a big puzzle for me how the PHP API call can access an attribute that is not even there.

I entered the following values in API Explorer:
[image: Api explorer screenshot]

You can see that the PHP code the API Explorer produces is exactly the same as I am using in the script.
Does anybody have any idea why this difference occurs?

EDIT: If @Pradeep's answer is correct, wouldn't it be logical to add this `'check_permissions' => TRUE` parameter in the PHP section of API Explorer? From my perspective, the code snippets in API Explorer should represent as exactly as possible the code that is *actually* executed.

Comment: The API explorer only returns the fields that has a non empty value in it. Eg if trxn_id for the contribution is empty, it will not return this value in the API explorer.

Comment: @jitendra The value is not empty, as the PHP API Call returns a value for the exact same Contribution ID.

Comment: Are checking the results for same contribution ID?

Comment: Yes, I am checking for the exact same Contribution ID.

Answer (score 3):

From api explorer the results are retrieved using rest api where check_permissions is always set to TRUE by default even though its been explicitly set via api params.

If you have check_permissions set to TRUE than api returns only those fields which are defined for the the entity. In your case the fields would be

```
civicrm_api('Contribution', 'getfields', ['version' => 3, 'action' => 'get']);
```

Try adding `'check_permissions' => TRUE` as a api parameter in your php code, it should return exact same results you get in api explorer.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: This worked (once). But when I removed the `check_permissions` param again (or set it to FALSE) I couldn't get back the old value with my PHP script. Instead, an empty string or NULL appears in the `payment_processor_id` attribute of API result now.